The zero component of Sympy Tensor object
TLDR: How to get the zero component of sympy.tensor.tensor.Tensor object?
I want to calculate hermitian conjugate of Dirac gamma matrix from sympy.physics.hep.gamma_matrices Mathematically, it is given by
gamma_μ_dagger = gamma_0 * gamma_μ * gamma_0.
So I need specifically 0-component of tensor, in an equation that is not quite tensor-like. I guess sympy.tensor.tensor.Tensor object is not that ideal for gamma matrices.
Another example would be
gamma_0^2 = I,
where I is identity matrix.
MWE
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.physics.hep.gamma_matrices import GammaMatrix
from sympy.tensor.tensor import TensorIndexType, tensor_indices, Tensor

# Define the dimension symbol
d = symbols('d', positive=True, integer=True)

# Define Lorentz index type and metric
Lorentz = TensorIndexType('Lorentz', dummy_name='L', dim=d, metric_name='g')
μ, ν = tensor_indices('μ ν', Lorentz)

gamma_0 = GammaMatrix("0")
gamma_μ = GammaMatrix(μ)

# Define the Gamma dagger operation
def gamma_dagger(gamma_matrix):
    return gamma_0 * gamma_matrix * gamma_0

print(gamma_dagger(gamma_μ))


Error
ValueError: Repeated index: 0

